# How can I (ReSTfully) verify that a user logged in via Facebook on my mobile app (using Facebook Graph) is really him?

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api

The user will have his own access token, the thing is, if this access token is stolen, and placed on another device, that user will gain access to this user's account. How can I prevent that and be more secure with authentication?

The user will be making API calls via a ReST API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind is to be careful about accesses (via a token) from a *new* IP address.  You can keep track of the IP address a token has been used from.  If there's an attempt to use the token from a new IP address, then send the user an e-mail asking them to confirm that this access is permitted by hitting a link.  Alternatively, you can require the user to supply a password when using an access token from a new machine.

I hope you may find that useful.  Best regards :)

Comment: its a mobile app. and i'd have offline access to the access token, meaning that the access token prolly never changes. and since it is mobile, IP addresses will always change. i'm wondering if there are some best practises. i'm reading about signatures here.

Comment: I was thinking that the IP address would change, but how many unique addresses would a mobile user typically have in a period of a month, say?  It's more than I imagined I guess!  So, yes I think you're on the right track with machine signatures.  Get identifying information about the machine the person is using, and allow access tokens to be used from a certain set of machines (not IPs).